# self.TableView not working for a TableViewController inside a ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am making a ViewController with 2 tableviews inside it. I am structuring it like
ViewController -> 2 x TableViewController classes. What I don't understand is that if I do [self.tableView reloadData] in the TableViewControllers it doesn't do anything.

If I do [tableViewA reloadData] in the ViewController it will execute the datasource methods in the TableViewController.

How do I call reloadData within the TableViewControllers?

Thanks,
Alan

Edit - This is how I setup the ViewController

```
if(self.reviewController == nil)
{
    self.reviewController = [[ReviewerTableViewController alloc] init];
}
if(self.approverController == nil)
{
    self.approverController = [[ApproverTableViewController alloc] init];
}
[self.reviewerTableView setDataSource:reviewController];
[self.approversTableView setDataSource:approverController];

[self.reviewerTableView setDelegate:reviewController];
[self.approversTableView setDelegate:approverController];

self.reviewController.view = self.reviewController.tableView;
self.approverController.view = self.approverController.tableView;
```

It seems like the datasource methods run once when I initialize them, but reloadData does not work inside.

I am basically just using the datasource methods in the UITableViewControllers and I am calling a method to pull data from the net. Once I get the data, I call reloadData, but the datasource methods are not executed.

Comment: I think you need to post some code for this question, it's hard to answer without it.

Comment: Agreed, code would be helpful. Also, are you following `UIVIewController` containment rules (e.g. `addChildViewController`)?

Comment: @Rob , I added some code for you to look at. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure the TableViewControllers' tableView properties are connected to the correct table views.

Comment: data does show up on the tableview if I hardcode data into the TableView, but I just can't get the reloadData to execute the datasource methods. I added some code if you would like to see if I set it up correctly in the UIViewController

Comment: I'd expect also something like:

Comment: self.reviewController.tableView = self.reviewerTableView; self.approverController.tableView = self.approverTableView;

Comment: Thanks :) that worked for me. I am guessing I need to delete the
self.reviewController.view = self.reviewController.tableView;
self.approverController.view = self.approverController.tableView; and replace it with yours

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling reloadData from the rootViewController? if so, you call

```
[self.reviewerTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Yes I know that works, but I am trying to call reloadData within the TableViewController, not the rootview. How do I do this? I tried [self.tableview reloadData], but it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems like the tableviews you have in your root view is using the delegate and datasource of your separate tableview class, but thats it. So calling self.tableview in the separate class won't point back to the rootview tableviews.However, I could be wrong without the whole code

Comment: recentViewController = [[RecentViewController alloc] init];
 recentTableView.delegate = recentViewController;
 recentTableView.dataSource = recentViewController;
 recentViewController.view = recentTableView;
 recentViewController.tableView = recentTableView; This is bit of code i used in my projects where I had 3 tables in 1 view. Check the part when setting the view

Answer (score 0):

I would create a UIVIewController that implements the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols.  Create two outlets, one for each tableview and make sure to wire them up in the interface builder.

then call [tableView1 reloadData];

Answer (score 0):

This seems very strange: you're trying to set the child UITableViewControllers' dataSource and delegates to be some local UITableViews declared (presumably) in your master view controller. It isn't supposed to work like this - the child UITableViewControllers are already the dataSource and delegate to their own implicit table views. There's no need to wired them up to separate UITableViews.

EDIT: I am assuming your "TableViewController" classes are UITableViewControllers. If not, then what you're doing may be valid, but I'd need to see all the code, headers included.